# Add Custom Theme in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

to change the theme of android application and android complete phone are different things ,I did read a lot of post related to changing to android application theme ,anyone can guide how can I add my custom them to android phone ? I mean I have an image I want to use that image as android phone background theme .Thanks in advance  .

Comment: You should be more specific, you just want to add the background? Do you want to theme every single image on your android?

Comment: hi I want to create a theme for every single icon image on android , means one background image will be as background of wallpaper that will be also work for background of lock screen and other icon images will be change whole android launcher icons as a theme . .

Comment: like if I have already installed skype ,by using my application them it will change skype icon so on for other launcher icons also . .

Comment: @aftab-Are you asking about this...http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html..??

Comment: Hi NilayOnAndroid no , not this one because this is for changing of application theme not android phone theme . Like to change the applications icons+home screen background ,colors scheme etc . .

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do that with a app, but if you have a rooted device and you are running a custom room that supports the theme chooser then you can do a theme based on theme chooser.

This are some examples of custom roms that supports theme chooser.

- CM ROM
- AOKP ROM
- AOSPA ROM